# Files in the assets directory are taking too long to get served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assets, sprockets

we are using ruby on rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2p290 on our project. One thing that I have noticed right away is that files from the assets directory are taking too long to load.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:28] "GET /users/new HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.5349
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:28] "GET /assets/new.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.2372
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:28] "GET /assets/new.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.5664
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:29] "GET /images/ios-back.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 19134 0.0062
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:29] "GET /images/app_logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 5415 0.0086
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:29] "GET /images/tick.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1968 0.0067
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:29] "GET /images/tick-standard.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2038 0.0048
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:29] "GET /images/tick-premium.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2060 0.0016
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:29] "GET /images/footer-back.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6507 0.0033
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:30] "GET /users/new HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.7324
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:30] "GET /assets/arrow_down.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.6284
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:30] "GET /assets/credit-cardlogos.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.7940
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:30] "GET /assets/facebook.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.8387
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:30] "GET /assets/twitter.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.9933
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:30] "GET /assets/rss.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 1.1291
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:31] "GET /assets/text_bold.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.9268
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:31] "GET /assets/text_italic.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 1.0190
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:31] "GET /assets/text_underline.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 1.0234
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:31] "GET /assets/text_list_numbers.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 1.0200
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2012 21:58:31] "GET /assets/text_list_bullets.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 1.0228
```

As you could see from the log, static files are taking a worrisome amount of time to get served. Is there something I am missing here? This page in question here is a simple landing page with static elements.

Comment: are you in the production environment? have you precompiled your assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem. I just landed on this project and was not fully aware of the assets used. The project that I am working on is using typekit and this is adding considerable loading times to the pages. Now what I am trying to figure out is getting the typekit library to serve faster or to just get those fonts locally.